# Extra condition on symprod in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to do something like this-

```
symprod(expr,j,a,b)
```

but i don't want j to vary continuously from a to b, but it excludes a particular point say c between a and b.
is there any short one line way to do this?
actually i want to write Lagrange formula for polynomial interpolation given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition) in one line.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the symbolic math toolbox, so I can't test any code, but it seems that what you want could be done by dividing `expr` by itself evaluated in `j=c`.

This is not valid MATLAB code, but something like this:

```
symprod(expr/(expr|j=c),j,a,b)
```